# A way to check next letter in Python after the current letter is detected?

Tags: python, parsing

```
May  1 00:00:00 date=2018-04-30 time=23:59:59 dev=A devid=1234 msg="test 1"
May  1 00:00:00 date=2018-04-31 time=00:00:01 dev=A devid=1234 msg="test 2"
```

Above is a sample of a log file that I am trying to convert into csv by checking letter by letter for `=` and save as a column value in a row.

I managed to capture columnValue if the value after the `=` is not a string. 
Below is a part of the code that extracts the value.  There is a part of the line where after `=`, there is a string with spaces in between. This broke the extract to start a new find. Is it possible to check the next letter for `"\""` and then start saving letter by letter until the next `"\""` so that I can save the Column Value as a string?

I'm using python 2.7

```
def outputCSV(log_file_path, outputCSVName, colValueSet):
    data = []
    f = open(log_file_path, "r")
    values = set() # create empty set for all column values
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content] #List of lines to iterate through
    colValueSet.add("postingDate")
    for line in content:
        new_dict = dict.fromkeys(colValueSet, "")
        new_dict["postingDate"]= line[0:16]
        findingColHeader = True # we have to find the columns first
        findingColValue = False # After column found, starting finding values
        col_value = "" # Empty at first
        value = "" # Empty value at first
        start = False
        for letter in line:
            if findingColHeader:
                if letter == " ":
                    # space means start taking in new value
                    # data is in this structure with space prior to column names -> " column=value"
                    start = True
                    col_value = ""
                elif letter == "=":
                    findingColValue = True
                    start = False
                    findingColHeader = False
                elif start:
                    col_value += letter
            elif findingColValue:
                if letter == " ":
                    new_dict[col_value] = value
                    value = ""
                    col_value = ""
                    findingColHeader = True
                    start = True
                    findingColValue = False
                else:
                    value += letter
        data += [new_dict]
    with open(outputCSVName, 'wb') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = list(colValueSet)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
    print("Writing Complete")

# findColumnValues(a) would calculate all column value from the file path
outputCSV("ttest.log", "MyProcessedLog.csv", findColumnValues("test.log"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try something like this:

```
>>> a = 'May 1 00:00:00 date=2018-04-30 time=23:59:59 dev=A devid=1234 msg="test 1" '
>>> a.split('=')
['May 1 00:00:00 date', '2018-04-30 time', '23:59:59 dev', 'A devid', '1234 msg', '"test 1" ']
>>> parts = a.split('=')
>>> b = []
>>> for i,j in zip(parts, parts[1:]) :
...     b.append( (i[i.rfind(' ')+1:], j[:j.rfind(' ')]) )
... 
>>> b
[('date', '2018-04-30'), ('time', '23:59:59'), ('dev', 'A'), ('devid', '1234'), ('msg', '"test 1"')]
>>>
```

I could make a cute one-liner, but I think this way it's easier to understand for you, when you see all intermediate results and can grasp the main idea -- split the line at `=` signs, use the last word as a keyword and the rest as the value.

Comment: Hi, how do I put the key value pairs into csv formats with key as headers and values in each row?

Comment: please, ask a different questions, I cannot write code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` module for Python (it's good to know it for any advanced text processing):

```
data = '''May  1 00:00:00 date=2018-04-30 time=23:59:59 dev=A devid=1234 msg="test 1"
May  1 00:00:00 date=2018-04-31 time=00:00:01 dev=A devid=1234 msg="test 2"'''

import re

for line in data.split('\n'):
    print(re.findall(r'([^\s]+)=([^\s"]+|"[^"]+")', line))
```

Outputs:

```
[('date', '2018-04-30'), ('time', '23:59:59'), ('dev', 'A'), ('devid', '1234'), ('msg', '"test 1"')]
[('date', '2018-04-31'), ('time', '00:00:01'), ('dev', 'A'), ('devid', '1234'), ('msg', '"test 2"')]
```

The explanation of this regular pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/VOaMjs/1).